# Turn off Strict standards error on localhost(windows 7) usbserver joomla virtuemart

Tags: php, joomla, localhost, virtuemart

I've tried a lots of settings (error settings) in php.ini and joomla, but nothing works. I get this error:

> Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method

I can get these only on local server, not on internet hosts. I searched about these errors, I get a lots of options for php error off, but none of them works. I've found these errors mostly for localhost. So, it's not serious but annoying. I use Joomla 2.5.x and Virtuemart 2.6.

Comment: If any of these items of software are issuing notices and warnings, it is generally a good idea to fix them. What messages are you getting? Which of these packages is issuing them?

Comment: Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method 

I can get these only on local server, not on internet hosts. I searched about these errors, I get a lots of options for php error off, but none of them works. I've found these errors mostly for localhost. So its not serious but annoying. I use joomla 2.5(?)  and virtuemart 2.6...

Comment: Why not see what code is pointed to by the line number PHP supplies in that error message? Can you edit into your question some of the code featuring the problematic line?

Comment: (Turning off PHP errors is correct on live machines, but quite wrong locally, since it masks the problem rather than fixing it).

Answer (score 0):

Change the values further down in php.ini

if im right it starts from line 441

Comment: Changed , but not any effect.

Comment: did you change the values without the ; in front?
And restart USBwebserver?

Comment: Yes of course. Only joomla error settings hide the half of the errors. php.ini settings do nothing. Error notices are the same. I google a lot, try a lots of settings, but nothing...

Comment: Don't forget to restart your Apache server after chaning the php.ini file!